# Windows Phone - Show UI from DLL

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

For research purposes I need to know whether it is possible during programm execution to download a dll from a server and call a graphical user interface inside the dll.

Which steps should I consider on downloading and loading the assembly?

1. Download
2. Parse File to DLL?
3. Assembly.Load()?
4. Call UI

My goal is to program many thik-clients for several unknown tasks (at startup)
hope someone understand my problem and could give me an advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your idea is not allowed by the [App certification requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184843%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) Microsoft has set and will break the following rules:

2.1 Your app must be fully functional when acquired from the Windows Phone Store.

2.3 Your app must not jeopardize the security or functionality of (a) Windows Phone devices or (b) the Windows Phone Store and must not have the potential to cause harm to Windows Phone Users.

4.1 The assembly and data files must be packaged as an XAP file package. Visual Studio generates the necessary XAP package and manifest files.

5.1.4 The app must be testable when it is submitted to Windows Phone Store. If it is not possible to test your app for any reason, including, but not limited to, the items below, your app may fail this requirement.

And then I didn't even mention the rules about security (chapter 5.4).